# Why Java in Chrome browser is not actual

Tags: google-chrome, java, browser-plugin

Chrome tells me:"The Java plug-in was blocked because it is out of date." I actualise it to newest version by .exe file on refered link http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp but Chrome still tells me that plug-in is out of date.

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get that error, it means Chrome detects a newer version of Java plugin. You can check the status of the your Chrome plugins by entering `chrome://plugins` to your Omnibox / address bar.

You should see something like this:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome plugin]

Clicking on `Download Critical Security Update` will bring you to the Java plugin download page. Follow the instructions to update Java.

Comment: I install it (again). 

After instalationI still see this:

Java(TM) (2 files) - Verze: 10.5.1.255 Stáhnout důležitou aktualizaci zabezpečení
Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.5.1 for Mozilla browsers

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the same reason why you have to keep downloading flash for all your browsers.

You can fix it by downloading the chrome version of java, there's an update button usually that shows up with that message.

EDIT: Install this: http://java.com/en/download/chrome.jsp

Comment: I already do this